# Почему процесс прерывается?

Tags: c++

```
char a;

while ((a = getch()) != 'exit') {
    if (a == '1') {
        char path1[100], path2[100];
        cout << "Type First Adress" << endl;
        cin.getline(path1, 100);
        cout << "Type Second Adress" << endl;
        cin.getline(path2, 100);

        CopyFile(path1, path2, true);
        cout << " File is Copied " << endl;
    }
}
```

хотя я поставил код `while ((a=getch()) != 'exit')` не выскакивать, только он выходит? что сделать, чтобы программа не выходила при нескольких нажатиях enter, пока не наберется exit -^ enter!

Comment: Ну во-первых в глаза бросается 2 открывающих фигурных скобки, и одна закрывающая?! А во-вторых, что за условие выхода из цикла вы хотели сделать? Когда будет введено 'exit' с клавиатуры или что?

Comment: да, то тех пор пока ты не набрал "exit" - enter, программа работала при всех нажатиях enter, пока не напечатана exit.Т.е ввожу первый адрес //enter, второй адрес //enter (он переносит файл), но я еще хочу продолжить работу с программой, например хочу перенести еще 1 файл без перезапуска программы

Comment: не поможете???

Answer (score 3):

В одну переменную типа `char` не может поместиться строка `"exit"`, кроме того, запись `'exit'` должна выдавать warning *multi-character constant*.

---

Вариант 1:

```
string s;
do
{
    ...
    cout << "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> s;
} while (toupper(s[0]) != 'N'); // toupper из <cctype>
```

---

Вариант 2:

```
cout << "Type exit for finish" << endl;
string s;
do
{
    ...
    s.push_back(getch());
} while (s.find("exit") == string::npos);
```

чтобы строка `s` случайно не заняла всю память, можно проверять, есть ли на её конце "e", "ex" или "exi", если нет, то делать `s.clear();`

Comment: пусть будет "с", как сделать вышесказанное?

Comment: изменил ответ

Comment: а как сделать повтор всего цикла? я хочу так:

if (toupper(s[0]) == 'Y') чтобы он повторил процесс, а еще лучше чтобы он сделал clrscr и давал тот эффект, что программа типо запустилась снова и просит у тебя повторно что ей делать?

Уточню, у меня программа такая:
Выводит как бы меню, 1) 2) 3) просит нажать на цифру одну, ты нажимаешь и соответственно номеру выполняется процесс, например копирование файла, он скопировал, а теперь просит (Y/N?) я нажимаю Y и она зачищает экран и опять выдавая меню просит что тебе сделать.

Знаю долго пошло, но помоги прошу

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Я имею ввиду то, что просто надо сделать то, что Вы написали

    string s = "Y";
    do
    {
        if (toupper(s[0]) == 'Y')
        {
           ...
           /* делаете что хотите
              очищаете экран, перерисовываете меню, просите ввести цифру, прибавляете 42 к переменной
           */
        }
        ...
        cout << "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> s;
    } while (toupper(s[0]) != 'N'); // toupper из <cctype>

Answer (score 1):

[@navi1893](/users/4969/navi1893)

Just for Fun

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

main ()
{
  char a, str[100], buf[5];
  int i = 0;

  buf[4] = 0;
  while (1) {
    buf[i] = getch();
    i = ++i % 4;
    if (strncmp(buf,"exit",4) == 0)
      break;
    printf ("xaxa buf = [%s] -> Enter line:\n",buf);
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    printf ("line = %s type 'exit' for finish\n",str);
  }

  printf ("End\n");
}
```

Попробуйте, поиграйтесь.

Comment: если честно он сложный для меня, для новичка, много непонятных вещей увы =Р а попроще нельзя?

Comment: А что, конкретно, не понятно ?